# Send_keys not working with variables in loop

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i need to create a loop with data imported from an excel sheet and fill some informations from a website using selenium. But when I create variables with the data, the 'SEND_KEYS' function doesn't work.

Theres the code and error:

#CODE

```
tabela = pd.read_excel('DADOS.xlsm')
for i, placa in enumerate(tabela["PLACAS"]):
motorista = tabela.loc[i, "MOTORISTA"]
dt = tabela.loc[i, "DTS"]
print(placa, motorista, dt)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com.br")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input").send_keys(motorista)
```

#ERROR

```
>>>line 541, in send_keys {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)), line 148, in keys_to_typing for i in range(len(val)):
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The error code you presenting is not shown in your question code

Comment: if variable ' motorista' contains multiline of string, use ActionChains

Comment: if the loop is a function, you have to include `global motorista` to acess the variable in the function.